# beginBitmapFill to Fill shape as a background cover works

Tags: easeljs, createjs

I'm building a game with createjs and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
var IMG = loader.getResult("imageID");
this.model.graphics.beginBitmapFill(IMG).drawRect(0, 0, window.width , window.height);
```

The image should cover the background no matter what size the image is. Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, or what isn't working with the code you shared.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I ended up using a standard cover background image in the container of my canvas and just drawing all the elements on top of it.